# Add Redactor field to searchindex

Tags: craft3, search, redactor

Is it possible to add a redactor field to the search index? I'm importing about 160 posts from a WordPress blog and the client has said it is absolutely essential that the posts themselves are searchable.
So far I've run `/craft resave/entries`  if I run with the flag `--type 'blog'` it only saves the titles, if I run `--type 'postContent'` (or `--section`) I get this error: `No entries exist for that criteria.`  (I'm not 100% on my knowledge of `--type` and `--section`).

None of the actual post content is in the search index and my entries are unsearchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you checked *Use this field’s values as search keywords* under Settings → Fields → **Your field**

With that in place, run `./craft resave/entries --update-search-index` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#resave-entries)) and your entries should start showing up in your search results.